# Space efficient way to search for substrings

Tags: regex, string, algorithm

I have a set of variable length strings, and I would like to verify that a variable length prefix string exists in at least one of the strings in that set. And strings can be added removed between consecutive searches.

The difficulty is that I do not want to store the strings of the set, but instead a space efficient representation of the set.

As an example, consider that I have the following set of strings:

```
S = {"abcd","aaaaaaaaa","dcba"}
```

searching for `a` should return `True`, but searching for `b` should return `False`. I want to search the set without storing the strings in memory.

Without storing the strings, a possible solution is to use a finite-state automaton (fsa) to represent the sequence of chars that make each string in the set. In other words, I would build the regex that matches all strings in the set. However I am not sure that it would be more space (memory) efficient than storing the strings. I also would like to add and remove strings from the set, and re-computing the fsa is probably too costly in terms of computation time.

I was thinking in using a classification algorithm, such as K-means or an SVM, but was wondering if there are any space efficient algorithms for this problem.

Comment: You want a "trie": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: I cannot store the strings, so there is no possible way for me to iterate over the set.

Comment: Is this a question about how to compress a string in memory or about how to store a set of string[representation]s so that it can be efficiently searched?

Comment: Thanks for the "trie" recomendation, I did not know it.

Comment: Why not store your fsa instead of the regex? Then you don't have to rebuild it every time.

Comment: @Bergi: I want to store a representation that can be efficiently searched. By efficient I mean that the representation is space efficient (much less space than the original strings). It can of course be slower that an algorithm that uses the original strings. But it must be faster than simply enumerating all possible sequence of chars and checking if the string exists in the representation of the set.

Comment: I understant that I could just build an fsa to represent the strings (or a trie as suggested by ruakh). But I also want to add and remove strings from the set and then run a new search. How easy is it to modify the fsa to reflect the changes to the set ?

Comment: Depends on the representation of the fsa and the input format of your string :-) It should be possible to do in about `O(sizeOfString + log sizeOfSet)`, though. Notice that a trie only saves space for shared prefixes, so depending on your data a fsa might be smaller (yet more complex).

Comment: You must have your strings _somewhere_ : what is the source of these strings, and what is the longest prefix you might want to search for? What is this "set" you cannot iterate over (yet somehow you want to iterate over it). Perhaps a little more detail might make the solution more obvious.

Comment: After having looked at trie's, this is the solution that I was looking for. Although wikipedia mentions that a DAG can be more space efficient, I believe a trie is more easy to work with.

Answer (score 0):

The conversation started by user ruakh in the comments reveals that the best answer is to use a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), a certain kind of tree data structure.